# On Demand Resources "0 Asset Packs"

Tags: swift, ios9, on-demand-resources

I recently started implementing On Demand Resources to my app. Everything is fine and dandy when I deploy the app to my phone from Xcode. But when I upload the binary to iTunes Connect it says "0 Asset Packs":

[image]

The asset tags in Xcode look fine:

[image]

Here's what the build settings of Assets looks like:

[image: Assets]

I'm testing via TestFlight and in the app I get an error saying "The requested application data doesn't exist."

I tried the following:

- Removed / readded the resource tags in Xcode
- Uploaded 3 slightly different binaries to the store
- Turned off / on beta testing
- Removed / readded testers

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I am currently suffering from the exact same problem. I am sorry that I don't have an answer to it yet, but I'll share it if I find the answer. Unfortunately, there are not a lot of help and information regarding ODR, I wonder how many people use this feature...

Comment: I found this link : https://community.unity.com/t5/iOS-tvOS/Second-preview-build-for-iOS-9-On-Demand-Resources-and-App/td-p/2382167 . One of the users indicated "Found the answer. If any build check at iTunes side is failed - ODR resoureces are not proceed. So, e.g. if you are uploading build for tvOS over 200MB, it will be blocked by iTunes Connect before ODR will be checked, so you'll always see:
On Demand Resources
Yes 0 Asset Packs". Do you know how we can understand if build check is failed or not on iTunes Connect, and why it fails?

Comment: After spending a lot of time on it, I think I found a way to make the TestFlight build work, and it's not pleasant nor I believe useful, but might lead towards the solution. So if I upload the same build twice under different  version numbers and download one of the versions from TestFlight, app wouldn't work; however, after installing the first app version if I change the version through TestFlight and download it to the phone without deleting the other version build on my device, magically it works. (But if I delete the app before updating it with the other build, it doesn't work.)

Comment: @Perex19 thanks for investigating. I don't think this is a viable solution for TestFlight testing, cause we can't make sure the users follow this complicated path. Apple should fix this issue, this bug literally makes apps unusable. Do you know if these builds would work on the App Store?

Comment: I submitted my app yesterday, waiting for the result of Apple's review.

Comment: After submitting the build, build details changed to show as "On Demand Resources Yes 14 Asset Packs". I hope that the build will work when it gets published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the problem is, it seems to be resolved now. Asset packs seem to show the correct number of Asset packs in the iTunes Connect, and the apps downloaded through test flight now work properly. I guess they got aware of such a problem and fixed it, and we just happened to test our apps in this unlucky time.