# On-demand resources uploading failure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, on-demand-resources

Recently I have faced with problem of uploading on demand resources. I am using Xcode 9.0 for uploading app to AppStore and every uploading finishes successfully. But looking at iTunes Connect build details I can see, that on-demand resources are enabled, but there are 0 assets packs for this build.

There is one more interesting moment in this problem. Build number 3 of my app also was uploaded with on-demand resources and everything works great with that build. But builds number 4 and 5 doesn't have assets packs included. I reviewed changes in application - there are no changes connected with on-demand resources at all.

In Xcode->Build Settings -> Assets ->Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle is set to No. Also, size of one asset pack is around 5MB, total size of all packs around 150MB.

Maybe, someone had this problem too? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have checked Product folder inside the Xcode archive - there are all 36 assets packs, but iTunes Connect still shows 0 packs.

**UPDATE 2**
It seems, that it happened not once. Developers had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422752/on-demand-resources-0-asset-packs?rq=1) one year ago. I think, we should report a bug to Apple.

**UPDATE 3**
We tried to upload app with on-demand resources using Application Loader, but result was the same.

**UPDATE 4**
We tried to revert code to version where everything works great with on-demand resources and upload the same binary with different version number to iTC, but result is the same.

**UPDATE 5** We received an answer from Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS)

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). 
>   Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time.

I will post any updates here connected to this issue.

Comment: Seems this issue fixed now. We just uploaded the same binary with another number and all 36 packs appears in iTunesConnect. Apple fixed this issue after 13 days of finding some workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 10 it won't allow ODR Anymore unless you go back to legacy mode 
so this works for me
[image: Instructions]

Comment: Actually Xcode 10.1 supports ODR https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes.

Comment: So lets upgrade to Xcode 10 to Xcode 10.1 if it would solve it then and see

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot provide a solution to your problem... only tell you we have the same problem and what we've tried so far.

We have not changed anything connected with ODRs and every IPA uploaded to iTunes Connect shows "0 asset packs". The build currently available on the App Store has the same set of asset packs and is listed correctly in iTunes Connect.

We've tried the following:

1. creating a clean build;
2. changing the version and build numbers;
3. uploading with the Application Loader instead of Xcode;
4. validated the IPA - it does include the OnDemandResources directory with the correct number of items and files that look fine -;
5. using a different Mac to upload;
6. deleting everything in the "DerivedData" directory.

iTunes Connect still insists that all the uploaded IPAs use On Demand Resources but have no asset packs, and if you install them through TestFlight they consider the ODR tag as invalid. This doesn't happen when installing the App with Xcode, then the ODRs work as expected.

We've already written to Apple (both the iTunes Connect team and as a technical support ticket).

We will probably try more things while we wait for Apple's response.

-

update:

Also tried uploading the commit that 'represents' the App currently published, simply changing the version number. It didn't work, asset packs still not recognized.

One thing that might have changed since we uploaded is that we installed Xcode 9.1 beta. We don't use the beta for uploading, nor are the command line tools set to use the beta version of said tools.

Comment: This is stated as not being an answer. Please use comments when unable to post a direct solution to the problem.

Comment: We are using Xcode 9.0 for uploading. We will try to update Xcode to version 9.1 and upload it again. Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck? We also updated to Xcode 9.1 and tried again. It still doesn't work.

The iTunes Connect team replied to my support request but it seems this problem lies a bit outside of their field. They assume we have a "code level issue" (misconfigured Xcode project).

I'm sending them additional data they require to escalate the issue.

Comment: @Pedro we also tried to upload a new build with Xcode 9.1, but result is the same. I found that developers had the same problem around a year ago, one of them told that he sent app for beta review and assets packs appears. We tried to do the same, but iTC still shows 0 assets packs.

Comment: I have the same issue since Oct 27.  I have used a ticket for DTS on 30 Oct.   I'll wait and see.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/274455

Comment: @Pedro issue is fixed and on-demand resources works great again!. We uploaded the same binary with different build number and all 36 assets packs appears in iTC.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) We were struggling with the same issue for about a week but tried uploading a new build today, and though it still says: On Demand Resources Yes | 0 Asset Packs ... it turned out the build works just fine. Perhaps there was some change today and you should try a new build and see if it works.

We tried most of the options mentioned above before, that is rebuilding the project, using Application Loader, updating Xcode etc. but it still didn't work so we just continued to upload and test the testflight build.

(I know it's not much of an answer and would post it as a comment but looks like it's not possible without enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, it was asset image that was linked under 
`TARGET` -> `Resource Tags` check if any image from assets is added there or not